# Express/Node Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

This is a simple get request that displays the error, "Can't set headers after they are sent". I'm sending it back to a controller shown below. It does successfully log the contents of the database (doc), so the connections are good and it only throws this error when the line "res.json(doc)" is written. Also is there an alternative to the .each() method? It's telling me it's deprecated.

**server.js**

```
var app = express();

//db connection
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://userName:secretPassword@aws-us-east-1-portal.7.dblayer.com:10712,aws-us-east-1-portal.10.dblayer.com:10316/dbName", function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var contactList = db.collection("contactList");

app.get('/contactList', function (req, res) {

     var cursor = contactList.find();
     cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
         res.json(doc);
     });

});
```

**controller.js**

```
$http.get('/contactList').success(function (response) {
    $scope.contactList = response;
});
```

Comment: you are sending a response multiple times with the `each`function

Comment: Do you use an ORM, why is the `find` is not async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us the `toArray` method:

```
app.get('/contactList', function (req, res) {
  contactList
    .find({})
    .toArray(function(err, docs) {
      // TODO: Error handling
      res.json(docs);
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems to be sending the response back before the array is populated with 'doc'. I'm still not too familiar with how to make this synchronous.

Comment: What do you use to fetch data, mongoDB?

Comment: I edited the post to include the MongoDB connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger `res.json()` just once. This is the response you are sending to the client.

What you probably want to do is to aggregate the results and pass it as a single collection